# Alert function - Javascript as wait function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, alert, setinterval

my application is aps.net MVC, is I loading several images using ajax, by getting the mouse Y position, it works but if I move the mouse more than one pixel for example 100 it load all images at once!  To test the script, I added Alert, and when the user click ok, the image advance as it is supposed to do.  I tried setInterval and Timeout, neither worked.  Here is my code:

```
 $("#container2").bind('mousemove', function (e) {

        lastX = e.pageX - position.x;
        lastY = e.pageY - position.y;
        coordinate = "x=" + lastX + ", y=" + lastY;
        $('#pValue').val(coordinate);
        $('#lastX').val(lastX);
        $('#lastY').val(lastY);

        waitStep = lastY >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
        waitInc = waitStep;
        waitCounter = lastY;

        for (var n = 0; n < Math.abs(lastY); n += 1) {
            //    imageSequence[n] = new Image();
            dicom1.src = '/Home/GenerateImage?' + $.param({
                pX: pointXF,
                pY: pointYF,
                pZ: waitInc * sThickness
            });
            waitInc = waitInc + waitStep;
            alert(waitInc);


        }
```

Would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code explicitly iterates and loads an image for each pixel moved in the Y direction. Why is it coded that way if you don't want it to do that?

Comment: It is one 3D DICOM image and I am changing the Z axis by moving the mouse up and down on the canvas; it works but jumps to the last position without displaying the other layers.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var speed = 15;
var timeout = 0;
$("#container2").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (!timeout) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            timeout = 0;
            lastX = e.pageX - position.x;
            lastY = e.pageY - position.y;
            coordinate = "x=" + lastX + ", y=" + lastY;
            $('#pValue').val(coordinate);
            $('#lastX').val(lastX);
            $('#lastY').val(lastY);

            waitStep = lastY >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
            waitInc = waitStep;
            waitCounter = lastY;

            for (var n = 0; n < Math.abs(lastY); n += 1) {
                //    imageSequence[n] = new Image();
                    dicom1.src = '/Home/GenerateImage?' + $.param({
                    pX: pointXF,
                    pY: pointYF,
                    pZ: waitInc * sThickness
                });
                waitInc = waitInc + waitStep;
                alert(waitInc);
           }
        }, speed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute the code one time on 15, you can try :

```
var speed = 0;
$("#container2").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    ++speed;
    if (speed % 15 == 0) {
            lastX = e.pageX - position.x;
            lastY = e.pageY - position.y;
            coordinate = "x=" + lastX + ", y=" + lastY;
            $('#pValue').val(coordinate);
            $('#lastX').val(lastX);
            $('#lastY').val(lastY);

            waitStep = lastY >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
            waitInc = waitStep;
            waitCounter = lastY;

            for (var n = 0; n < Math.abs(lastY); n += 1) {
                //    imageSequence[n] = new Image();
                    dicom1.src = '/Home/GenerateImage?' + $.param({
                    pX: pointXF,
                    pY: pointYF,
                    pZ: waitInc * sThickness
                });
                waitInc = waitInc + waitStep;
                alert(waitInc);
           }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks again, but it did not work.  I am trying to replace the alter with wait function.